# Possible to get a contract/token's age using etherscan api?

Tags: etherscan

I want to programmatically get the age of a contract or token on the ethereum blockchain. Is there a reliable way to do this with the etherscan api?

Comment: Yes, via `http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=<YourTokenAddress>&apikey=<YourApiKey>`

Comment: The genesis block number of your token contract should be at the `blockNumber` field of first entry, provided that the `to` field of that entry is empty (otherwise, the token contract was created on-chain (i.e., from a function in another contract), in which case, I'm not so sure how you could obtain it via Etherscan API).

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks, will try this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via:

```
http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=<XXX>&apikey=<YYY>
```

Where `XXX` is your token address, and `YYY` is your Etherscan API key.

The genesis block number of your token contract should be at the `blockNumber` field of the first entry, provided that the `to` field of that entry is empty.

Otherwise, the token contract was created on-chain (i.e., from a function in another contract), in which case, I'm not so sure how you could obtain it via Etherscan API.

Comment: How do I do it manually?